# Add dataframe records to polygon and filter in R

Tags: r, shiny, polygon, spatial, shapefile

So I'm making an R-shinyapp with a leaflet map integrated in it.
I have all these records with a dateTime, coordinates and value in a dataframe (example-data shown below)

```
               dateTime longitude latitude    value
1   2020-12-16 17:01:20   5.39288  52.1695   7.8750
2   2020-12-16 17:01:17   5.13751  52.0565   6.6250
3   2020-12-16 17:01:14   5.06665  51.5589   7.9375
4   2020-12-16 17:01:14   5.06876  51.5407   7.8750
5   2020-12-16 17:01:10   5.37686  52.1628   7.8750
6   2020-12-16 17:01:10   4.48129  51.8972   8.4375
7   2020-12-16 17:00:56   5.36868  52.1512   7.2500
8   2020-12-16 17:00:50   5.37665  52.1625   7.9375
9   2020-12-16 17:00:40   4.76126  51.5904   8.6250
10  2020-12-16 17:00:28   5.03778  51.6557   8.2500
11  2020-12-16 17:00:19   5.39493  52.1604   7.4375
12  2020-12-16 17:00:18   6.00140  52.2250  11.5000
13  2020-12-16 17:00:18   5.38287  52.1591 -26.0000
14  2020-12-16 17:00:13   4.68015  52.0269   7.6250
15  2020-12-16 17:00:11   5.38129  52.2039   7.6250
16  2020-12-16 17:00:08   5.37653  52.1581   7.8125
17  2020-12-16 17:00:05   5.31345  60.3948   8.3125
18  2020-12-16 16:59:32   5.36609  52.1619   7.5000
19  2020-12-16 16:59:21   5.39023  52.1761   7.5625
20  2020-12-16 16:59:15   5.38635  52.1781   7.8125
21  2020-12-16 16:59:08   5.11014  51.5553   8.4375
22  2020-12-16 16:59:04  10.66060  59.8672  -0.6250
23  2020-12-16 16:58:59   5.07648  51.5539   8.1250
24  2020-12-16 16:58:49   5.35388  52.1633   8.0625
25  2020-12-16 16:58:46   5.39020  52.1735   7.9375
```

I also have these polygons which I got out of a .shp file and attached to a leaflet map.
I want to able to have those records shown above attached to the polygons so I can use a filter to show the minimum, maximum and average of all the values in each polygon.

I've tried looking for answers on here and elsewhere, but am completely clueless how I would go about this, so if you need any additional information I can provide it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to check which datapoints fall within the polygons based on location and join the data to the polygons. In that way, it becomes possible to do further data analysis. Personally, I would go with the  `sf` package to convert your point data to a spatial features object and then perform a spatial join.

```
#convert  data to spatial feature (assuming data is called 'df')
points <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

Check the crs of your data though! I assumed WSG1984 for now. Now that both of your data is in the form of spatial features (polygons and point data), you can use `st_join`to join the data (assuming they are in the same crs):

```
#perform spatial join
polygons_with_data <- st_join(points, nameofpolygonfile, join = st_intersects)
```

This function checks where points intersect with the polygon and then joins the data. You can use a variety of different ways of `join`, such as `st_within`, `st_within_distance`, etc..

Please let me know if you need any additional help.